# querying info from an existing dojo.itemfilereadstore

Tags: ajax, dojo

I'll start off by mentioning I'm a dojo noob.  That said,

I'm having trouble reading data from a `itemfilereadstore`.  When my page is loaded, I perform a `.fetch()` on a `itemfilereadstore`.  The ajax call retrieves some data from the server and my `onComplete` handler is executed.  My problem is after this store is populated (and after my `onComplete` handler is executed), I don't see a way to read its contents (enumerate its items) again without hitting the server.

How can I `fetch()` against this existing datastore without it trying to hit my webserver again?  Surely I can look up information that already exists in this object somehow?  The dojo documentation doesn't seem to have any obvious answers, what am I missing?

Comment: I've implemented a partial solution to this.  In my `onComplete` handler I'm saving off references to each item in a javascript Array as I iterate through them.  I can then iterate over this list of 'pointers' anytime I want.  This feels like a hack; there must be some way to use the `itemFileReadStore` directly?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is itemfilereadstore.query.  If all you need is to get all the elements, just a plain old query should do the trick.  If you need to filter, then you'll have to read up on the query syntax : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#query-syntax

Comment: Yea I thought this too. But to use query I have to call fetch() on my existing store. My store has a 'url' property which goes out and hits my webserver again every time I call fetch(). I shouldn't have to reload data that is already there. Maybe I'm missing something but having to re-download a json from a webserver each time I access an itemFileReadStore seems silly and a waste of time and bandwidth.

Comment: The last sentence above reflects my frustration with dojo, not your suggestion. The difficulty of using these itemFileReadStores is one of my biggest gripes with dojo (I have quite a few).

Comment: Argh, sorry I didn't notice this got some responses.  If this still hasn't been fixed, I would suggest you load your data with an XHR request and build the store manually by providing the "data" value.  This will cause a "fetch" call to just access the local JS values instead of calling the url provided.